# Why is the training time become longer when I implement a tensorflow version from pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I am implementing a tensorflow version of diffusion model, the original code is based on pytorch.
But I find that the training time for the tensorflow version is much long (about 4-5times). The opitimizer(including learning rate) and network architecture are excatly the same, and if I use a middle epoch(the same number for both version) to test trained model, the test loss for tensorflow version is much smaller that the pytorch version).

Does anyone have any ideas about the reasons?

Also, I find the three parts -- time for model forward, for calculating the gradients, and for backpropagation are all much longer in tensorflow that the pytorch version.

I found that in the original pytorch code, some of the functions in class(nn.module) is set to be torch.no_grad, so it is operated on CPU which decreases the time and memory. I tried to use with tf.device to set it to be operated in CPU in tensoeflow version, but it seems that it does not work. (two snapshots are added for pytorch and tf version, two functions are called in def **init** for the model class)

[pytorch version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAmEp.png)
[tensorflow version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etQHP.png)

Comment: Please add some reproducible code

Comment: @AndrzejO Thanks for replying, I found that in the original pytorch code, some of the functions in class(nn.module) is set to be torch.no_grad, so it is operated on CPU which decreases the time and memory. I tried to use with tf.device to set it to be operated in CPU in tensoeflow version, but it seems that it does not work. I add the snapshot for that part in this question.